# Linux command needing translating

Tags: linux

I have just started learning the Linux system and I need some help to translate the following to English:

```
grep WARNING readme.txt
```

and

```
grep WARNING readme.txt > warnings.txt
```

This is a homework question that i have researched myself but having trouble learning exactly what it means.

thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. find all lines in readme.txt containing the word "WARNING"
2. same as 1, but instead of displaying the results, put it in the file "warnings.txt"

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation of the `grep` command?

Comment: Do you know basic Unix shell syntax? Do you know what `> warnings.txt` means in general?

Comment: If this is homework, don't you have a teacher or textbook that explains things?

Comment: Thanks for help :) Not overly familiar with the syntax, this is one of my first days of learning this. Do you have any resources you recommend on this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try making a file on your computer named `readme.txt`.  Put some lines of text in there, and make sure that some lines say "WARNING" while other lines do not.

Then run your first command and observe its output.

Then run your second command and observe its output and observe what was written to `warnings.txt`.